# Apache Camel test and assert the JSON body field value with JSON Path Expression

Tags: java, apache-camel, jsonpath, json-path-expression, camel-test

I'm trying to check the field value of the body which is a JSON string with `JsonPathExpression`.

In the example below, the `JsonPathExpression` checks whether or not the root JSON object has the field named as "`type`". What I want to achieve is, to assert with the use of `JsonPathExpression` if the field value "`type`" equals to a certain String value.

**Note:** I know that there are other ways, by extracting the message body via `MockEndpoint#getReceivedExchanges` but I don't want to use that because it's out of the assertion scope.

Here is my test class;

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.model.language.JsonPathExpression;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MockTestWithJsonPathExpression extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    @Test
    public void testMessageContentWithJSONPathExpression() throws InterruptedException {
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:quote");
        mock.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mock.message(0).body().matches(new JsonPathExpression("$.type")); // how to test the content of the value
        
        /* Json string;
         * 
         * {
         *     "test": "testType"
         * }
         * 
         */
        String body = "{\"type\": \"testType\"}";
        
        template.sendBody("stub:jms:topic:quote", body);
        
        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("stub:jms:topic:quote")
                    .to("mock:quote");
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: You can try this evaluator to build the syntax for this: https://jsonpath.com/

Comment: @ClausIbsen Is there a way to retrieve the value of the json body with json path expression and check it?

Comment: @ClausIbsen Like mock.message(0).body().???(new JsonPathExpression(<json path here to field>).equalsTo(<value here>);

Comment: try take a look in camel-jsonpath source code for its own unit tests

Answer (score 1):

Following Claus' suggestion, we can take inspiriation from Camel's own [JsonPath unit tests](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jsonpath/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/jsonpath/JsonPathLanguageTest.java):

```
Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
exchange.getIn().setBody(new File("/or/mock/file.json"));

Language lan = context.resolveLanguage("jsonpath");
Expression exp = lan.createExpression("$.test");
String test = exp.evaluate(exchange, String.class);

assertNotNull(test);
assertEquals("testType", test);
```

Comment: It's useful to know (that's why I upvoted) how to evaluate the expression to get the field value but what I was searching for, setting the mock to expect the value of a field of the json body and still I can't see a way to do so. I was wondering if there was such a functionality.

Comment: @LeventDivilioglu not sure, would it be helpful to make the assert inside of `getMockEndpoint()`?